# Can you deploy XNA game application to WP8 in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, xna-4.0

As in title, I am trying to deploy my game application to my wp8 device in VS 2012, but it will only run the emulator and nothing else. 
There are no options for deployment other than 'start' unlike in a windows phone game(4.0) or a windows phone app on VS2012 where you can select 'Device'

Sorry if this question is a bit vague, just hitting a wall here and would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems strange, you say it runs in emulator without problems? Which one?

Comment: I actually got it working using application deployment.
But cant actively debug that way. The emulator it uses seemingly be default is Windows Phone Emulator - 512mb

Comment: Then you probably have a corrupt installation. I suggest that you reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

start option automatically updates when you open the project.as per your project it will be updated,if you open windows 7.1 project then 4 type of emulators will be displayed in the list .if you open wp 8 project then there will be only start option. when you connects the phone device to computer in that list you will get device option by selecting it you will be able to run projects on your deice. unless you connect any device to computer IDE will not display device option.